# Is there a way to force cast int to enum when that int does not represent a valid enum value?

Tags: c#, .net, enums

```
enum Answer : int { Yes = 1, No = 2 }
Answer answer = (Answer)100;
```

It throws, but I don't want it to. How?

Comment: What would you want to force it to?

Comment: Never mind, I'm stupid. Downvote more.

Comment: Eric Gunnerson blogged about this years ago- http://blogs.msdn.com/ericgu/archive/2004/05/10/129369.aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**No**, it does not throw. Your typecast line does exactly what you want.

#### Additional:

**enums** are purposely relaxed about accepting 'invalid' values, this is necessary when using bit-flags.

Comment: Yes- I would add though what you want is probably an entry for daily WTF!

Comment: Ricard, it is an example and not that far of, `answer = (Answer)3` for Yes and No would make some (sort of) sense.

Answer (score 0):

This goes against the concept of enums... They exist to ensure that the option exists. If you need 100 different values my advice is to loose the enum. If you just need "another value" you could do this:

```
enum Answer : int { Yes = 1, No = 2, OtherValue }
Answer answer = Answer.OtherValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to do this? Why not simply use an int if you are not using the features of the enum?

That said, the code does not pose any problem for me:

```
Answer answer = (Answer)100;
Console.WriteLine(answer); // prints 100
```

Answer (score 0):

Huh, it throws? Are you sure you are using C#? This code is perfectly valid and does what you want it to do!